# Import CSV with FeedMe - multiple categories

Tags: plugin-feedme

I'm attempting to use FeedMe to import a CSV list of entries exported from Google Sheets. I have a column labeled "Categories" and an entry with `category1,category2` as the value. I set up the feedMe job pointing to the CSV and the categories field to point to this column. However it is not importing/creating two categories (the expected behavior)rather it is just creating one category  with the name "category1,category2" -- am I doing something wrong as far as how to list out multiple categories in CSV? Can Feedme handle a comma separated list like this?

If I convert the sheet to a json, it produces: `"Categories": "Category1, Category2"` which does not work either - however if I edit the json to be `"Categories": ["Category1", "Category2"]` that works - but manually editing it is not really an option on my final spreadsheet as it will have over a 1000 entries.

If there's an easy way to convert the sheet/csv to correct Json I'd be open to that too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with CSV by setting a `dataDelimiter` in a `config/feed-me.php` files (see [docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/get-started/configuration.html)).

If you set the `dataDelimiter` to be `|` for example, then your CSV could be:

```
"title", "Categories"
"Some title", "Category1|Category2"
```

Doing this should let you import multiple categories from CSV.

Comment: This worked - thank you!